# How do I boot my iMac over the internet?

Tags: mac, internet, remote, osx-leopard, netboot

I am running **Mac OS X 10.5.8 Leopard** on a 2009 iMac. For when I am not home, how can I turn on/start up/boot my Mac over the internet? I have a Verizon Actiontec router if that helps and I will be using a laptop running Windows 7 whenever I am gone.

As a side question, can the free version of LogMeIn be used at the log in screen?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). I don't know, though, if your Actiontec router will let you remotely log into it (the router) and send a Wake-on-LAN packet to your computer. If not, you might consider getting a router that can run [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) firmware, which does support this.

Alternatively, there do exist power strips that can be remote-controlled over the network, but they tend to be a more expensive solution.

Update: This [link](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/16041) may be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't Wake-on-LAN require a local network? Is it a program, a protocol, or a method?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's a part of the Ethernet standard. Also, I added a link my answer that might help.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to have a static IP for your router or you should set up A dynamic DNS.  DynDNS is great but no longer free (as far as I know).  I have used no-IP you will need to log in regularly to keep the account active.

http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html

This will allow you to connect to your router from the internet. Very useful for many other things.

There is a way to do this but it is very complicated and not sure how it would be done for a mac. (sorry I am a pc)

Some people have used LogMeIn to start a computer over the internet that might be your best choice.

This video may help
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3syjuu7qYTA

Comment: LogMeIn does not start the computer. It can't do anything if the computer is off.